# Search result web part does not show User Profile Date fields in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, people-search

Here I am trying to get SP user's profile data where I want to show birthdate in sharepoint online but here i am simply not getting any date field result data.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SharePoint Online Admin Center->User Profiles->manage user properties->find and edit Birthday Property, make sure you select “everyone” for default privacy settings, and ticked “Indexed” in the search settings.

Then give the relevant birthday value to user profile and wait some time to apply this changes.

Comment: I tried it but still not wrking